# iOS Network Stack "What kind of network am I"?

Tags: ios, networking, encryption

Is it possible to detect the type of wifi encryption in use by an iOS device? We need to ensure that our app is only functional over a WPA2-Enterprise connection.

Comment: Yes it is. If I would have searched wi-fi vs. wifi I would have found it... Thanks.

Comment: If it is a duplicate then  Mark it yourself. You should see a button above your question.